# How to use both ribbon(Xml) and ribbon designer in office addin(Power point)

Tags: c#, winforms, office-interop, powerpoint-2010

I am facing a situation where i have to customize  existing context menu of power point? Previously i have used ribbon designer for ribbon interface .But now for context menu i have to use ribbon(XML).I have searched and found its is not possible to use both ribbon(XML) And ribbon designer simultaneously .

In this situation how do i customize context menu and as my requirements .Is there any way where we can customize context menu of power point for shape without using ribbon(XML)?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way where we can customize context menu of power point for shape without using ribbon(XML)?

No, starting from Office 2010 you need to use the Ribbon XML markup for customizing Office context menus. See [Customizing Context Menus in Office 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691832(v=office.14).aspx) for more information. Command bars were deprecated and are not used any longer.

You may find the [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx) helpful.